# images not appearing after changing .htaccess file in codeigniter 2.1.0

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|tp|files)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|Images|js|tp|files)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

after removing "index.php" from config file everything is working fine except that images are not displaying

Comment: are your images in an `Images` directory, or `images`? If you're on a unix-ish system, they tend to have case-sensitive file systems, and `Images` will be a completely DIFFERENT directory/file from `images.

Comment: working on windows and path is like.                                      projectname/Styles/Images/image.png

Comment: So use "Styles", not "images"

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|Styles|js|tp|files)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]                                   still not working